# Kafka transaction failed but commits offset anyway

Tags: java, spring, transactions, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to wrap my head around Kafka transactions and exactly-once.

I have created a transactional consumer and I want to ensure that I read and process all messages for a topic. Kafka still commits the offset if the transaction fails and the message is therefore lost.

> More formally, if a stream processing application consumes message A and produces message B such that B = F(A), then exactly  once processing means that A is considered consumed if and only if B is successfully produced, and vice versa.
>   [Source](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/)

Based on this I would assume that message A is not consumed and will therefore be reprocessed again. But how will this message be reprocessed?

I have found plenty of sources stating that if processing fails, then the message is not consumed. But I cannot find any sources mentioning how to reprocess the message if it not consumed. I appears that if a transactional consumer fails then Kafka will rollback but continue to commit the offset such that it can process the next message. But if Kafka commits the offset, then the previous message is lost?

I have found some Spring Kafka pages describing how to handle exceptions in the consumer. So you basically either stop the container or the entire application. I thought Kafka had some internal mechanics to handle this behaviour since the documentation states that message A is only consumed if message B is successfully produced. But if message A is not consumed then Kafka will still commit the offset and continue with the next message.

It feels like exactly-once only applies to cases where errors never happen. I honestly do not care if a message is consumed or not consumed if Kafka will commit the offset regardless. The message will be lost even if the message is not consumed, so it seems like I have to stop the container or application to make sure I do not lose any messages.

https://spring.io/blog/2017/12/01/spring-for-apache-kafka-2-1-0-release-and-1-3-2-2-0-2-available
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#annotation-error-handling
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1114

**Edit 1: I have added some example code below.**

I have a very simple Spring boot application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class KafkaTransactionMysteryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaTransactionMysteryApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager chainedTxM(JpaTransactionManager jpa, KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafka) {
        return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager(kafka, jpa);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "trans-topic")
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, transactionManager = "chainedTxM", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord record) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(record.value());
        if (true) {
            throw new Exception("Force rollback");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my application properties:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=127.0.0.1:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=127.0.0.1:9092

spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=mytrans
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=trans-topic-grp1
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.isolation.level=read_committed
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=RECORD
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
```

This is for the log for the above code when sending a kafka message from a console-producer:

```
2018-06-20 10:17:43.494 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Created Kafka transaction on producer [CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@55ef3ce1]]
2018-06-20 10:17:43.494 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [dk.kkflf.kafka.transaction.mystery.KafkaTransactionMysteryApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67f55772.listen]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'chainedTxM',-java.lang.Exception
2018-06-20 10:17:43.537 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.h.stat.internal.StatisticsInitiator    : Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
2018-06-20 10:17:43.541 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2018-06-20 10:17:43.543 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2018-06-20 10:17:43.545 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@4d13cb21]
hello stackoverflow
2018-06-20 10:17:43.545 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction rollback
2018-06-20 10:17:43.545 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
2018-06-20 10:17:43.545 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : rolling back
2018-06-20 10:17:43.547 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] after transaction
2018-06-20 10:17:43.547 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
2018-06-20 10:17:43.548 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Initiating transaction rollback
2018-06-20 10:17:43.549 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=mytrans0] Transition from state IN_TRANSACTION to ABORTING_TRANSACTION
2018-06-20 10:17:43.549 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=mytrans0] Enqueuing transactional request (type=EndTxnRequest, transactionalId=mytrans0, producerId=0, producerEpoch=21, result=ABORT)
2018-06-20 10:17:43.549 DEBUG 47970 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=mytrans0] Not sending EndTxn for completed transaction since no partitions or offsets were successfully added
2018-06-20 10:17:43.549 DEBUG 47970 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=mytrans0] Transition from state ABORTING_TRANSACTION to READY
2018-06-20 10:17:43.550 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction
2018-06-20 10:17:43.552 ERROR 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = trans-topic, partition = 0, offset = 39, CreateTime = 1529479063351, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 19, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = hello stackoverflow)

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void dk.kkflf.kafka.transaction.mystery.KafkaTransactionMysteryApplication.listen(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord) throws java.lang.Exception' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: Force rollback
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:267) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1071) [spring-kafka-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1051) [spring-kafka-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:998) [spring-kafka-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:866) [spring-kafka-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:724) [spring-kafka-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Force rollback
    at dk.kkflf.kafka.transaction.mystery.KafkaTransactionMysteryApplication.listen(KafkaTransactionMysteryApplication.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at dk.kkflf.kafka.transaction.mystery.KafkaTransactionMysteryApplication$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7b3cab85.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at dk.kkflf.kafka.transaction.mystery.KafkaTransactionMysteryApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1375ca24.listen(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:248) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2018-06-20 10:17:43.553 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Commit list: {trans-topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=40, metadata=''}}
2018-06-20 10:17:43.553 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Committing: {trans-topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=40, metadata=''}}
2018-06-20 10:17:43.554 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=trans-topic-grp1] Committed offset 40 for partition trans-topic-0
2018-06-20 10:17:43.693 DEBUG 47970 --- [rans-topic-grp1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=trans-topic-grp1] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2018-06-20 10:17:43.696 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=trans-topic-grp1] Received successful Heartbeat response
2018-06-20 10:17:43.747 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=trans-topic-grp1] Fetch READ_COMMITTED at offset 40 for partition trans-topic-0 returned fetch data (error=NONE, highWaterMark=40, lastStableOffset = 40, logStartOffset = 0, abortedTransactions = [], recordsSizeInBytes=0)
2018-06-20 10:17:43.747 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=trans-topic-grp1] Added READ_COMMITTED fetch request for partition trans-topic-0 at offset 40 to node localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
2018-06-20 10:17:43.748 DEBUG 47970 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=trans-topic-grp1] Sendin
```

The source code is also accessible on github 
https://github.com/kkflf/kafka-transaction-mystery/tree/SO-50922050

**Edit 2: My consumer will now rollback on exceptions and not commit the offset to Kafka. (Hurray!). I am now trying to link to together with a JPA transaction to a MySQL Database.**

The code below will persist the MyMessage object to my MySQL database but it will rollback the Kafka transaction and replay the same Kafka message again(Which is a good thing). This will lead to duplicate entries in the MySQL database because the Kafka did a rollback but the JPA did not rollback. How do I overcome this situation - It seems like KafkaListener and my Repository does not share the same transaction session?

I have uploaded the latest changes to https://github.com/kkflf/kafka-transaction-mystery/tree/SO-50922050-edit2

This post is becoming very long, so I have pushed the log file here:
https://github.com/kkflf/kafka-transaction-mystery/blob/SO-50922050-edit2/log-SO-50922050-edit2.log

Main application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class KafkaTransactionMysteryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaTransactionMysteryApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager chainedTxM(JpaTransactionManager jpa, KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafka) {
        return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager(kafka, jpa);
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory(JpaTransactionManager jpa, KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafka) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedTxM(jpa, kafka));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps());
    }

    private Map<String, Object> consumerProps() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "trans-topic-grp1");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "trans-topic", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, transactionManager = "chainedTxM", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void listen(List<String> records) throws Exception {
        for (String record : records) {
            MyMessage message = new MyMessage(record);
            messageRepository.save(message);
            if (record.equals("fail")) {
                throw new Exception("Forced rollback - msg: " + record);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Repository to persist MyMessage object to the database:

```
@Repository
public class MessageRepository {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    //Mandatory to make sure this is never executed outside a transaction
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void save(MyMessage message) {
        em.persist(message);
    }

    public MyMessage findById(Long id) {
        return em.find(MyMessage.class, id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't use `auto.commit.enabled=true` with transactions; when a `KafkaTransactionManager` is injected into the container, the container will send the offsets to the transaction if the listener exits normally.
2. For rollbacks, see the `AfterRollbackProcessor`. The `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor` is invoked after the transaction is rolled back; it re-seeks all unprocessed records so they will be returned again by Kafka on the next `consumer.poll()`.

References you find for stopping/starting the container was for older versions of spring-kafka. For example, when NOT using transactions, we now provide the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` (which performs a similar function to the `AfterRollbackProcessor` when using transactions).

Comment: I assume you refer to spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit, which I have set to false. How do I initialise `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor` and add it to my KafkaListiner/consumer or will spring handle this by default(as the name suggest)? Does `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor` re-seek all un processed records and return them back to a KafkaListener or do I have to create my own consumer which poll? I have updated my question with source code that I am testing on. Very simple spring boot application.

Comment: I cannot find `AfterRollbackPostProcessor`, do you perhaps refer to `AfterRollbackProcessor` which `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor` implements.?

Comment: It was a typo, sorry (no `Post`). Spring kafka automatically configures the default processor; there is nothing more for you to do; the failed message will be redelivered after the rollback.

Comment: Ah `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, transactionManager = "chainedTxM", rollbackFor = Exception.class)` - don't use `@Transactional` you need to inject the chained TX manager into the container instead - otherwise it knows nothing about the transaction and it will commit the offset. Also, when configured this way, the container will send the offset to the transaction (for success) instead of committing it itself.

Comment: Actually, I have one additional question. It is not really a problem, but something I have been wondering. How come `spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix` is based on producer when the consumer also uses this prefix? I guess it is because the `KafkaTransactionManager` uses an internal producer to send the transaction states(prepare, abort, commit, etc) to the kafka transaction coordinator/transaction log and therefore acts as a producer.

Comment: I have added a second edit to my post. Kafka no longer commits the offset after a failed transaction, which is really great. I have tried to add a repository to the application to save an entity to a database using a transaction. This new transaction does however not rollback when Kafka performs rollback. Thank you for your help so far. I will add a final solution to this post once I got everything working in case anybody runs into the same issues as me.

Comment: According to the log, the JPA transaction **is** being rolled back `>JpaTransactionManager        : Rolling back JPA transaction... `. Again, you **don't need `@Transactional` on the listener**. The way it works is thus: 1. The txMgr checks out a producer from the factory and calls `beginTransaction`; 2. the producer is bound to the thread so that any downstream `KafkaTemplate` operations use that producer; 3. the container uses the producer to send the offset to the transaction (if the listener exits normally). 4. the transaction is committed (or rolled back); 5. producer is cached for reuse.

Comment: Yep, I understand that I do not need `@Transactional` on the listener. And the log does say that the transaction is rolled back, but the data is still saved to the database. I am using an MySQL database, so I can check the database content after executing the application. I am truncating the database between each run to make sure that I do not mistake old data as new data.

Comment: Well, that has nothing to do with Kafka; I am not a JPA expert; sorry.

Comment: No problem. Maybe you knew something about it. Thank you for your time. I appreciate it a lot. I will update my question with a working example once I find the error.

Comment: I found the problem. `Executing identity-insert immediately` is in the log. Basically JPA is inserting a new entity in the database and let the database assign the ID, so it has to be inserted immediately. This action is not rolled back. Problem solved ;)