# Kafka Streams with single partition to pause on error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a single Kafka broker with single partition. The requirement was to do following:

1. Read from this partition
2. Transform message by invoking a REST API
3. Publish the transformed message to another REST API
4. Push the response message to another topic

I am using Kafka Streams for achieving this using the following code

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();`
KStream<Object, Object> consumerStream = builder.stream(kafkaConfiguration.getConsumerTopic());
consumerStream = consumerStream.map(getKeyValueMapper(keyValueMapperClassName));
consumerStream.to(kafkaConfiguration.getProducerTopic(), Produced.with(lStringKeySerde, lAvroValueSerde));
return builder.build();
```

FOllowing is my configuration:

```
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, String.join(",", bootstrapServers));
        if (schemaRegistry != null && schemaRegistry.length > 0) {
            streamsConfig.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, String.join(",", schemaRegistry));          
        }
        streamsConfig.put(this.keySerializerKeyName, keyStringSerializerClassName);
        streamsConfig.put(this.valueSerialzerKeyName, valueAVROSerializerClassName);
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
        streamsConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        streamsConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1000);
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, FailOnInvalidTimestamp.class);
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, "exactly_once");
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 1);
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, 1);
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, DeserializationExceptionHandler.class);
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, ProductionExceptionHandler.class);
        streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION,StreamsConfig.OPTIMIZE);
        streamsConfig.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, compressionMode);
        streamsConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1000);
```

I was looking for a mechanism to do the following in my KeyValueMapper:

1. If any of the REST API is down then I catch the exception
2. I would like the same offset to be kept on looping until the system is back up OR pause the consumption till the system is back up

I've checked the following links but they do not seem to help.

[How to run kafka streams effectively with single app instance and single topic partitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54416023/how-to-run-kafka-streams-effectively-with-single-app-instance-and-single-topic-p)

Following link talks about KafkaTransactionManager but that would not work I guess the way KStream is initialized above

[Kafka transaction failed but commits offset anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922050/kafka-transaction-failed-but-commits-offset-anyway)

Any help / pointers in this direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Currently I am using a custom flavor of ProductionExceptionHandler to skip certain types/flavors of exceptions using the `ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse.CONTINUE` while the `ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse.FAIL` to rely on retrying of the same message again (this kills the streams and thus forcing the Kubernetes pod to restart) which is not really an ideal way we would want to retry the same message in case any of the API is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not really supported. Pausing the consumer is not possible in Kafka Streams.

You can "halt" processing only, if you loop withing your `KeyValueMapper`, however, for this case, the consumer may drop out of the consumer group. For your case, with a single input topic partition and can only have a single thread in a single `KafkaStreams` instance anyway, hence, it would not affect any other member of the group (as there are none). However, the problem will be that committing the offset would fail after the thread dropped out of the group. Hence, after the thread rejoin the group it would fetch an older offset and reprocess some data (ie, you get duplicate data processing). To avoid dropping out of the consumer group, you could set `max.poll.interval.ms` config to a high value (maybe even `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) though -- given that you have a single member in the consumer group, setting a high value should be ok.

Another alternative might be te use a `transform()` with a state store. If you cannot make the REST calls, you put the data into the store and retry later. This way the consumer would not drop out of the group. However, reading new data would never stop, and you would need to buffer all data in the store until the REST API can be called again. You should be able to slow down reading new data (to reduce the amount of data you need to buffer) by "sleeping" in your `Transformer` -- you just need to ensure that you don't violate `max.poll.interval.ms` config (default is 30 seconds).

Comment: Thanks @Matthias J Sax for the information. I guess it is a short coming if you ask me when using processor, transform etc as one would seldom like to lose that many messages when other systems etc are down OR probably am misunderstanding the purpose of streams. I was trying the following which I believe should work:

**1.** Invoke _KafkaStreams.close_

**2.** Invoke _Thread.sleep_ for 300 seconds

**3.** Throw a RuntimeException to Kill the instance

**4.** This will trigger restart of kubernetes pod and thus consumer being able to re-consume the same offset again

Comment: I did not say that you would loose any message -- you would just reprocess some messages. -- You can also kill the instance as you describe an rely on Kubernetes to re-start it, what will trigger a retry -- of course, this is not a general solution because it's rely on an external system that restart the application. But it should work -- it's of course quite "heavy" and not really elegant -- blocking and retrying and increasing max.poll.interval.ms seems to be more elegant.

Comment: "Another alternative might be te use a transform() with a state store. If you cannot make the REST calls, you put the data into the store and retry later." - this indeed seems to be the most elegant way. But how to retry messages from the state store, if we keep receiving new messages through our stream? Also would such retries be scalable across multiple consumers working on the same stream?

Comment: You can either embed the retry in the `process()` itself, or use punctuations. -- But if there is only one partition, you cannot parallelize processing.